# String in list replacing previous index strings while concatenating

Tags: c#, ms-word

I want concatenate strings in my norm list but they are replacing each other not concatenating. Here is the code. I used string.join, string.concat,and aggregate methods but none of them doing their job.

```
List<string> norm = new List<string>();
            Application application = new Application();
            Document doc = application.Documents.Open(@"E:\abdullah\import.docx",false,true);
            foreach (Paragraph paragraph in doc.Paragraphs)
            {

                Style style = paragraph.get_Style() as Style;
                string styleName = style.NameLocal;
                int count = 0;
                if (styleName == "Heading 1") 
                {

                    count++;
                }
                else
                {

                        string text = paragraph.Range.Text;
                        norm.Add(text);


                }

            }
            for (int i = 0; i < norm.Count;i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(norm[i]);
            }
            string a=string.Join(string.Empty, norm);
            Console.WriteLine(a);
            doc.Close();
            application.Quit();

            Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: I think string.Empty would not be a valid separator? Have you tried using something else? And have you checked whether `norm` contain what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a StringBuilder?

```
    var sb = new StringBuilder(); 
    foreach (var nor in norm)
    {
      sb.Append(nor);
    } 
    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: String builder isn't working either. Each string in a list containg a sentence and in the output there remains only a single last indexed sentence.

Comment: @AbdullahKhan Is the code you posted in a method that's being used by multiple threads? Also, is your norm List local to this method/block of code?

Comment: I think it is being used by multiple threads because when it try to read doc file it give file is in use promp thats why I turned the readonly parameter true while reading file. Norm is local to main method.